# Ember. Extend Router for addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-addon

I would like to have common routes defined in my addon, which can be shared by our multiple projects.

I saw a solution in the Ember Forum but I'm not sure if this is the right approach or If I'm doing it rigth.
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-extend-router-by-mixin-defined-in-an-addon/7553/5

addon/utils/route_setup.js:

```
     export default function(self) {
          self.route('home', {path: ''});
          self.route('thanks');
       };
```

app/router (dummy app):

```
  import Ember from 'ember';
  import config from './config/environment';
  import coreMap from '../utils/route-setup';

  const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
     location: config.locationType
  });

  Router.map(function () {
    coreMap(this);
  });

   export default Router;
```

Error:

```
   Error: Could not find module `utils/route-setup` imported from `dummy/router`
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it was just the path
import coreMap from 'project-app/utils/route-setup';